# R - Compare values in two columns in different rows

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `df` as seen below with two features, a departing city and an arrival city. Every two rows information is stored about a going and a return flight.

```
  Departure Arrival
1    A          B
2    B          A
3    F          G
4    G          F
5    U          V
6    V          U
7    K          L
8    K          L
```

There is some inconsistency in the data where the same flight is repeated as it can be seen in the last two rows.

How is it possible to compare for every two rows the departure city of the first row and the arrival city of the second row, and keep the ones that are equal.
The dataset is very big and of course a for-loop is not considered an option.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In the cases where you have two consecutive rows of going flight as in rows 7 and 8, do you get after it the actual return in row 9, or does it go straight to another flight?

Comment: I posted a couple options below, but I'd say you're going to get ripped here for posting something that's pretty google-able. before 20803 other people say it, try searching first.

Comment: It goes to another flight. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a method that compares the pairs of rows using `head` and `tail` to line them up.

```
# find Departures that match the Arrival in the next row
sames <- which(head(dat$Departure, -1) == tail(dat$Arrival, -1))
# keep pairs of rows that match, maintaining order with `sort`
dat[sort(unique(c(sames, (sames + 1)))),]
  Departure Arrival
1         A       B
2         B       A
3         F       G
4         G       F
5         U       V
6         V       U
```

Note that the two variables have to be character vectors, not factor variables. you can coerce them to character using `as.character` if necessary.

**data**

```
dat <-
structure(list(Departure = c("A", "B", "F", "G", "U", "V", "K", 
"K"), Arrival = c("B", "A", "G", "F", "V", "U", "L", "L")), .Names = c("Departure", 
"Arrival"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```

Comment: This works really well unless there is a repeated row followed by a row that has the same Departure as the previous Arrival, for example with `dat2=rbind(dat,c("L","K"),c("K","P"))` or `dat3=rbind(dat,c("L","T"),c("T","P"))`, then it removes the wrong rows.

Comment: Given the data provided, the returned values will be identical (except for the row names). If other columns are available, these might be used in a group-level operation to differentiate them.

Answer (score 2):

So you just want unique flight paths? there are a number of ways to do this, I'd think the fastest would be with data.table, something like:

```
 library(data.table)
 df <- as.data.table(df)

 uniqueDf <- unique(df)
```

you can also use the duplicated function, something like

```
 df <- df[!duplicated(df), ]
```

should do nicely.

Comment: This works well if you want to remove duplicate rows but I think order is important here. What if there are two sets of flights from the same location and destination? This will remove all but the first pair.

Comment: @Eumenedies fair, way to read the whole post! I'd actually suggest from a method standpoint that this person is misreading what are actually unique flights as duplicates baring any other identifying info. I'd be hesitant to remove them without knowing for sure they're the same....

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it this way:

```
right = rep(df[c(T,F),"Arrival"]==df[c(F,T),"Departure"],each=2)
df[right,]
```

This returns:

```
   Departure Arrival
1          A       B
2          B       A
3          F       G
4          G       F
5          U       V
6          V       U
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution, if it works for you:

```
df[duplicated(paste0(df$Departure,df$Arrival))==F,]
```

Comment: this is a nice add on to mine, since it illustrates how to do this by duplicate columns. I'd say give that there are only two though...

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't look for unique records, it specifically checks if a row is a duplicate of the row before.

Adding a new column with a 1 if the row has repeated:

```
 for(i in 2:length(df$Departure)){df$test[i]=ifelse(df$Departure[i] == df$Departure[i-1] & df$Arrival[i] == df$Arrival[i-1], 1,0)}
```

Loops can be slow though:

`library(data.table)`

```
df$test2 = ifelse(df$Departure == shift(df$Departure) & df$Arrival == shift(df$Arrival), 1,0)
```